# 1 clickinstall has installed magento 1.8 but the latest version is 2.1

Tags: magento, web

I have purchased hosting and now have to build website in magento but my 1 clickinstall has installed magento 1.8 but the latest version is 2.1 what version should i install ? and how to manually install the magento 2.1 on my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to check php and mysql versions in your hosting server. If your server has:
php version >= 5.5.x, where x is 22 or greater and mysl version >= 5.6

only then you can install magento version 2.1, otherwise you will have to upgrade hosting.

To install magento 2.x manually, there are 3 options:

- using composer (for this you will need ssh access)
- using git checkout
- using browser wizard (which is just like you used to do with magento 1.x installations)

Please follow http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install-quick-ref.html for more information.